# Python: how can I identify a decimal number in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

How can I identify decimal numbers in a list of strings, in order to remove them? Ideally in a single operation, something like `content = [x for x in content if not x.isdecimal()]`

(Sadly, isdecimal() and isnumeric() don't work here)

For instance, if `content = ['55', 'line', '0.04', 'show', 'IR', '50.5', 'find', 'among', '0.06', 'also', 'detected', '0.05', 'ratio', 'fashion.sense', '123442b']` I would like the output to be `content = ['line', 'show', 'IR', 'find', 'among', 'also', 'detected', 'ratio', 'fashion.sense', '123442b']`

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve? Filter strings in a list that contain a decimal point? Keep those, discard those? Please do include inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Sorry, this was a badly phrased question. Edited.

Comment: you wrote *a list of strings*. Post that list

Comment: Please do include a sample list and the expected output. Try to think of edgecases (whitespace? thousands-separators?). Think the problem through.

Comment: Thanks. There should not be whitespace. Thousands-separators... maybe but I don't mind if they slip through.

Comment: @Unstack, should integers also be removed?

Comment: Yes, integers too, if possible. Otherwise I can remove those in a separate operation (with isdecimal/isnumeric).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a regex to test if a string is a decimal:

```
import re
content = ['line', '0.04', 'show', 'IR', '50.5', 'find', 'among', '0.06', 'also', 'detected', '0.05', 'ratio', 'fashion.sense', '123442b']
regex = r'^[+-]{0,1}((\d*\.)|\d*)\d+$'
content = [x for x in content if re.match(regex, x) is None]
print(content)
# => ['line', 'show', 'IR', 'find', 'among', 'also', 'detected', 'ratio', 'fashion.sense', '123442b']
```

Comment: That's very good, but it lets single-digit numbers slip through.

Comment: @Unstack You want to keep integers, don't you? single digit numbers are integers, so they are in the result list.

Comment: @Unstack Anyways, I edited my answer, it should now remove integers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to [Mr Geek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6275103/mr-geek) answer, You should also check out the python's docs on [Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Comment: this should be a comment then not an answer!

Comment: Thanks for your correction, just realised what I did.